# Why is ReferenceQueue always empty?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm trying to use a ReferenceQueue to free resources used by the garbage collected objects. The problem is that my reference queue is always empty, even if there is proof that one of the referenced objects was garbage collected. Here's a very simple, self-contained JUnit test that illustrates what I am trying to do (track the removal of an object):

```
@Test
public void weakReferenceTest() {
    ReferenceQueue<Object> refQueue = new ReferenceQueue<Object>();
    Object myObject1 = new Object();
    Object myObject2 = new Object();
    WeakReference<Object> ref1 = new WeakReference<Object>(myObject1, refQueue);
    WeakReference<Object> ref2 = new WeakReference<Object>(myObject2, refQueue);
    myObject1 = null;

    // simulate the application running and calling GC at some point
    System.gc();

    myObject1 = ref1.get();
    myObject2 = ref2.get();
    if (myObject1 != null) {
        System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject1 is still valid.");
        fail();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject1 has disappeared.");
    }
    if (myObject2 != null) {
        System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject2 is still valid.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject2 has disappeared.");
        fail();
    }
    Reference<? extends Object> removedRef = refQueue.poll();
    boolean trackedRemoval = false;
    while (removedRef != null) {
        if (removedRef == ref1) {
            System.out.println("Reference Queue reported deletion of MyObject1.");
            trackedRemoval = true;
        } else if (removedRef == ref2) {
            System.out.println("Reference Queue reported deletion of MyObject2.");
            fail();
        }
        removedRef = refQueue.poll();
    }
    if (trackedRemoval == false) {
        fail();
    }
}
```

For me, this always prints:

```
Weak Reference to MyObject1 has disappeared.
Weak Reference to MyObject2 is still valid.
```

... which is fine, but the test always fails due to `trackedRemoval` being `false` at the end - the `ReferenceQueue` is always empty.

Am I using the `ReferenceQueue` and/or the `WeakReference`s wrong? I also tried `PhantomReference`s instead, but it makes no difference.

Interestingly, if you convert the Unit Test to a regular `public static void main(String[] args)` method, then it works like a charm!

Can anyone explain this specific behaviour? I've been searching for an answer to this for quite a while now.

Comment: "At the same time or *at some later time* it will enqueue those newly-cleared weak references that are registered with reference queues." This means that the JVM is allowed to do extremely wacky things with putting the reference into the reference queue.

Comment: IIRC it *usually* happens when the GC gets invoked again. The reason is most probably efficiency, but I don't know the exact mechanism.

Comment: @hexafraction: You are right, in theory it could take forever for an object to be enqueued into a Reference Queue. But then again, what else is this mechanism good for?

Comment: @maaartinus: I tried invoking the GC multiple times - at least in my little unit test it didn't make any difference. Perhaps it would make a difference if more time elapses between the GC calls.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a race condition to me. When the GC determines that the object referenced by `myObject1` is GCable, it will GC it and clear it from the `WeakReference`. It will then add that `WeakReference` to a "pending reference list". There is a Reference handler thread which will remove from that list and add to the appropriate `ReferenceQueue`. The above is an implementation detail which supports the javadoc

> At the same time or at some later time it will enqueue those
>   newly-cleared weak references that are registered with reference
>   queues.

When your code reaches

```
Reference<? extends Object> removedRef = refQueue.poll();
```

the reference handler thread must not have added your `WeakReference` to the `ReferenceQueue` and therefore the `poll` returns `null`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, considering that the GC usually runs in its own thread. However, if this is really true, then what are ReferenceQueues really good for? Did the authors of the ReferenceQueue class really not consider this?

Comment: @Alan47 I just realized I never answered your comment. `ReferenceQueue` was designed exactly as stated in the API documentation. You used `poll()` which is a non-blocking call that returns immediately either with a `Reference` or with `null`. Use `remove()` if you want to wait for the registration.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this might not be a definitive answer, but at least it gets the Unit test from the question to run properly. Instead of the regular `java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue`, I tried using the following class:

```
public class MyReferenceQueue<T> {

    private Set<WeakReference<T>> WeakReferences = new HashSet<WeakReference<T>>();

    public void enqueue(final WeakReference<T> reference) {
        if (reference == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add reference NULL!");
        }
        this.WeakReferences.add(reference);
    }

    public WeakReference<T> poll() {
        Iterator<WeakReference<T>> iterator = this.WeakReferences.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            WeakReference<T> ref = iterator.next();
            T object = ref.get();
            if (object == null) {
                iterator.remove();
                return ref;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The downsides of this approach are:

- Need to explicitly `enqueue` the `WeakReference`s to track
- Only works for `WeakReference`s, not for `PhantomReference`s (because their `get` method always returns `null` by definition)

With this, the Unit Test succeeds as intended. Plus, it does not rely on the GC to do anything in particular (like adding a `WeakReference` to some queue), except that it invalidates the `WeakReference` (which it always does reliably). Perhaps it does something super ugly that I'm not aware of, but for now it gets the job done.

**EDIT**

Here is the updated JUnit-Test that makes use of my custom implementation.

```
public class WeakReferenceTest {

    @Test
    public void weakReferenceTest() {
        MyReferenceQueue<Object> refQueue = new MyReferenceQueue<Object>();
        Object myObject1 = new Object();
        Object myObject2 = new Object();
        // note that the second constructor argument (the reference queue) is gone...
        WeakReference<Object> ref1 = new WeakReference<Object>(myObject1);
        WeakReference<Object> ref2 = new WeakReference<Object>(myObject2);
        // ... instead we enqueue the references manually now
        refQueue.enqueue(ref1);
        refQueue.enqueue(ref2);
        // the rest of the test remains the same
        myObject1 = null;

        // simulate the application running and calling GC at some point
        System.gc();

        myObject1 = ref1.get();
        myObject2 = ref2.get();
        if (myObject1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject1 is still valid.");
            fail();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject1 has disappeared.");
        }
        if (myObject2 != null) {
            System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject2 is still valid.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Weak Reference to MyObject2 has disappeared.");
            fail();
        }
        Reference<? extends Object> removedRef = refQueue.poll();
        boolean trackedRemoval = false;
        while (removedRef != null) {
            if (removedRef == ref1) {
                System.out.println("Reference Queue reported deletion of MyObject1.");
                trackedRemoval = true;
            } else if (removedRef == ref2) {
                System.out.println("Reference Queue reported deletion of MyObject2.");
                fail();
            }
            removedRef = refQueue.poll();
        }
        if (trackedRemoval == false) {
            fail();
        }
    }

}
```

This test succeeds as intended.

Comment: I don't see how you used your own class where a `ReferenceQueue` is expected. And note that a `HashSet` does not preserve ordering.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've edited the answer above, it now contains the updated JUnit-Test. And yes, I know that `HashSet` will not preserve the ordering of elements. For this scenario, I do not really care about the ordering. However, since the new class is named `Queue`, perhaps a `SortedSet` would be the more proper way to implement it.

Comment: What would you do in case of a thousands references? You have to go through all of them as you don't know which one gets cleared. You have to do it all the time as you don't know when GC happens. But yes, I can imagine that it can be useful in some scenarios (few costly resources to be cleared ASAP).

Comment: Yes, good point - this might be an efficiency bottleneck. Just like you said, in my scenario there are 20 to 50 references we are talking about, and I need to free their resources as soon as possible.